# Connection of socket io creating problems in updating notifications?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, mern

I want a system that when a new client comes on the candidate request page , admin should get notified and notifications should increase by 1 but here the socket may be running multiple times or any other reason , the value is updated by 2 and sometimes 4.
**Client side request to become a candidate when arrive on this page**

```
 const id = localStorage.getItem('voterId');
    const [constituencies, setConstituencies] = useState([]);
    const [parties, setParties] = useState([]);

const [newCandidateRequest, setNewCandidateRequest] = useState({
    party: '', constituency: '', description: '',
})
socket.connect();
useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('newCandidateRequest');
    console.log('Disconnecting the socket io')
    socket.disconnect();

}, [])
```

**Server Side**

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A new client connected.");
  socket.on("newCandidateRequest", () => {
    console.log('New candidate request comes');
    io.emit("newNotification");

  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A user disconnected');
  });
});
```

**Admin Side**

```
 const [requests, setRequests] = useState([]);
    const { notifications, updateNotifications } = useNotify();
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleNewNotification = () => {
            console.log('Updating the value of notifications');
            updateNotifications();
            console.log("notifications " + notifications);
        };
        socket.connect();
        socket.on("newNotification", handleNewNotification);
        return () => {
            console.log('Turning socket off');
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('data is here ' + notifications);
    }, [notifications]);
```

Comment: The way you use socket.io seems weird. The point of using it is usually to be connected to the server while you are on the page but you connect, send message and immediately disconnect. Regarding the multiple notification updates i guess you see this log `console.log('Disconnecting the socket io')` multiple times in DevTools right? That could mean your code is in a function which react calls everytime it re-renders html but from the code you've shown it's not possible to tell.

Comment: What details are needed to answer it.  Can you please tell me how can i make this connection in best way?